# Elements in footer different with firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css

So I noticed something weird when testing website in different browsers. In Firefox  element and h3 heading are on same line, but in Chrome  element is under the border and not in line with title element.

```
<footer class="main-footer">
   <h3>Author1<a href="#home" class="foot-nav">BACK TO TOP</a></h3> 
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
    .main-footer a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: .75em;
        float: right;
        color: #626262;
        padding-top: 3px;
        margin-top: -38px;
     }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, if anything I would say that Chrome is showing the expected result given that `margin-top: -38px;` will move it up 38 pixels. I'm unable to reproduce your issue with the code you have provided, please create a Stack Snippet which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to position an inline element. You'd be better off positioning an inline-block.

```
.main-footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: right;
  color: #626262;
  padding-top: 3px;
  /*margin-top: -38px;*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/rLqLAY

You'll notice that this looks the same in Firefox and Chrome.

On the other hand, every browser has a stylesheet of its own, which can cause differences between how things are rendered. I would recommend that you use reset css, like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), at the beginning of your CSS. This should prevent many headaches in terms of browser differences.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, when `float` is used an `inline` (or `inline-block`) element automatically becomes a `block` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float. I think there maybe other issues at play which will require more code to be provided by the OP before we can help.

Comment: I resolved the issue with separating <h3> and <a>. Somehow margins what I put to <h3> affected also <a>.